# Undefined index: usernamecheck in ~\index.php on line 44

Tags: php, ajax, xampp

I have this `usernamecheck` in two places:

- once in **Ajax**
- once in **PHP**

Ajax code snippet :

```
function checkusername(){
    var u = ("s_username").value;
    if(u != ""){
        _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'Checking...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "index.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true){
                    _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
    ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
```

PHP code snippet:

```
include_once("connect.php");
$s_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
```

I am getting the error in the **PHP** code in the above line

Please tell me how to fix it. I am new to **PHP**
Also, I am running this on xampp server

Comment: $usernamecheck = isset($_POST['usernamecheck'])?$_POST['usernamecheck']:''; $s_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $usernamecheck);

Comment: well, the first time the index.php page is loaded, there is variable posted (under that name) so before you replace anything, you should check it's existence)

Comment: Cool ! It worked ! Thanks guys ... appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change PHP code on this:

```
$s_username = isset($_POST['usernamecheck']) ? preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']) : NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Will check it as answered as soon as stackoverflow allow me to :P

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to use `isset` because **PHP** throws *unidentified index error* whenever a value isn't initiated.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the hard way